# Twilio Resonse and Dial Verb just gets read out

Tags: twilio

I am currently trying to set up an automated call redirection using Twilio. I have set up a webhook with Spring Boot and return a call verb. 
But when I call the number connected to the webhook I only get a voice that reads the number i wanted to redirect to. What did i do wrong? 
Here is the Request Mapping:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/call")
public String call(){
    Number number = new Number.Builder("+XXXXXXXXXXX").build();
    Dial dial = new Dial.Builder().number(number).build();
    VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial).build();
    String xml = response.toXml();
    return xml;
}
```

And thats the Response I get when testing it with postman:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial><Number>+XX XX XXX XX XX</Number></Dial></Response>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer. Forgot to specify the Content-Type Header to be xml. Thus (I guess) Twilio just took it as text and not as TwiML.

Comment: That is correct! It is read as text and then assumed to be `<Say>` (or `<Message>` if you are responding to an incoming SMS). Glad you got it sorted!